Handling enums with SQLAlchemy and pydantic when enum name and value is different
I have a Postgres DB table with a status field with type int.
That field can have 2 values, which I represented with this enum:
class Status(Enum):
   inactive = 0
   active = 1 

I also have a pydantic model representing this table, and I want to define the status field as a Status enum, like this:
class MyTable(BaseModel):
   status: Status

   class Config:
     validate_assignment = True

    @validator('status', pre=True)
    def validate_status(cls, value) -> Status:
        return Status[value]

The validator above works to map the int values from the DB to the Status type. But then I am having issues when saving this object to the DB, since the code does not know how to map the Status type back to an integer. Error is: can't adapt type 'Status'

What can I do to fix the mapping back to the DB?
Is there a better way to handle this case? I'd like to keep the human readable names in the enum


2 small changes should solve this for you:

Update your ModelConfig to use enum values, your model instances will then serialize using int instead of the enum representation.
Update the logic of your validator to only manipulate string values. (Allow enum values to go unchanged, and ints will automatically be coerced by pydantic.)

class MyTable(BaseModel):
    status: Status

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
        use_enum_values = True      # <-------- Change 1

    @validator('status', pre=True)
    def validate_status(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):  # <-------- Change 2a
            return Status[value]
        return value                # <-------- Change 2b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m1 = MyTable(status=Status.active)
    m2 = MyTable(status='active')
    m3 = MyTable(status=1)

    assert m1 == m2 == m3 == {'status': 1}

